# SSL certificate behaviour within Joomla 1.5

Tags: security, ssl, joomla

One of the requirements of our Joomla backend admin session is to encode the user's IP within the cookie to prevent replay attacks. If I implemented SSL for the admin session, would this solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have an ssl cert for the domain, it'd be a simple matter of enabling the requirement in the GlobalConfig.

Or you could just adjust how your session is handled (file vs db) and lenght.

http://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist_4_-_Joomla_Setup